# How to authorization user in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have `user` table :

```
| id | username | password | role_id |
|:--:|:--------:|:--------:|:-------:|
| 1  |  user1   | password | 10      |
| 2  | user2    | password | 11      |
```

and the `role` table :

```
| id | name |
|:--:|:----:|
| 10 | admin|
| 11 | superadmin|
```

it is mean the `user` table should has relationship with `role` table.

I get confused how to make authorization with relation table, I have try to include this method in my `user` model, but is not working :

```
public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class, 'role_id', 'id');
}
```

and this is my `Gate` in authserviceprovider :

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();
    Gate::define('isSuperadmin', function ($admin) {
        return $admin->role == 'superadmin';
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you go `$admin->role` it will return a model instance of the role, which is not a string, you should have

`$admin->role->name === 'superadmin'`

And a side note it makes more sense to me to call the admin var `$user` since it might be a regular user

Answer (score 0):

Use [spatie/laravel-permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) package instead for roles/permissions management.